# Android Media player from file stored in memory

Tags: android, audio, media-player

i have this problem, i create a app, in this app i record audio ogg file, i store file in memory (i see the file using DDMS) , 
when i wont to play the file audio i have a error
in this link you can see the source
main:
http://pastebin.com/PWE9FsxT
android manifest:
http://pastebin.com/p39J1Y6i
logcat
http://pastebin.com/ktyFWPXq
please help me
Best Regads
Antonio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes because sometimes mediaplayer is not ready ,  put a condition before playing a
sound so that sound will play when media player is completely released .

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you write me a example? or can you see a how to or web site can i'll study a solution?